# Disable specific Tomcat HTTP post logging

Tags: http, jsf, tomcat, post, polling

on my JSF page I have a primefaces poll (`<p:poll>`) which checks if a backend is still running every second. The problem now is that the HTTP POST method, which checks the backend, is writting a logging entry into the Tomcat log every second. This will likely produce a lot of logging data which may lead to some problems with the server.
My question is now how I can prevent this POST method from writting into the tomcat log file?

Comment: What does the logging message look like?

Comment: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [05/Sep/2016:10:05:05 +0200] "POST /nameOfWarFile/faces/nameOfPage.xhtml HTTP/1.1" 200 1954

Comment: XXX is the ip address . i just censored it,

Comment: One line is 112 bytes, then you get 3600*112 = 393kB/hour is 9.2MB per day. If you rotate daily and zip that, it will be less than 1MB I think, so don't think that will result in any problems. But if you really want to solve it: Find the class in tomcat that is writing this log line and override that class in one way or another so it only writes the log lines you want (or prevent them being written at all, that could be done by configuring the tomcat log config)